# QR Reader in android

Tags: android

I want to integrate QR Reader in my android app without integrating third party tool and also need auto scan feature .I reviewed few tutorials using zxing libraries but scanning is not done in them.It generally captures image to sdcard and then access it and which doesnt give result every time....
Please help experts .

Answer (score 8):

If you want to Integrate QR reader which is not a third party tool, then i suggest download the Zxing code which is an open source.

1. Call the activity which initiates the scan, from your app activity.
2. Regarding saving to the sd card, Zxing doesn't do that, it analyzes the image in focus and tried to find the match until the activity is cancelled or a match is found.
3. Have a look at ZXing QR reader app before you can integrate it in yours.

I have integrated the ZXing QR reader successfully and it works without a problem. Requires some effort though. Good luck.

Comment: I tried it but unable to make it work, will u pls send some code on ashutoshdixit.it@gmail.com

Comment: i cannot help you with the code, but i can tell you this, call "CaptureActivity" activity from your app, it takes care the rest.

Comment: thnx for your reply.But I tried it and can't make it to work.Actually problem is if I put qrcode image to sdcard it reads correctly but image captured by camera is little bit distorted and app can't get sumthing out of it and crashes.so the problem is scanning or detecting only qrcode from big image containing other stuffs also

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the Zxing Barcode Scanner app, which does QR Code decoding with auto scanning.
I'm sure of it, because i used it last week :)

[BarcodeScanner.apk](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/downloads/list)

Greetings Ralf

Answer (score 0):

Integrate ZXing's Barcode Scanner app with your app without having to install the app separately.

[Step-By-Step Guide](http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/integrate-zxing-barcode-scanner-into-your-android-app-natively-using-eclipse/#comment-159)

Answer (score 0):

A great alternative is Google's barcode scanner available in the Google Play services through the namespace `com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode`. It's fast and robust (it does all the parsing locally) and it's all made with just a few classes, giving you full control of the source code. And of course it supports all the [standard barcode formats](https://developers.google.com/vision/barcodes-overview).

A good place to get started is [Android QR Code Reader Made Easy](https://www.varvet.com/blog/android-qr-code-reader-made-easy/). This will get you up and running in no time and you can easily build further upon the code provided or equally easily implement it in your existing project!

Give it a try, I bet you'll love it!